# MS Access: Separating out first and last name into separate fields

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a field with thousands of records. In those records are a bunch of names.

The problem is both the first and last name are listed together (rather than in two different fields).  How would I go about separating them out. The format right now for the names is `John Smith`

```
FirstName: Left([PlayerName],InStr([PlayerName]," ")-1)
```

I tried this but it did not work. It just returned `#Func!` for each record in my `FirstName` query field

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Nick, are you entering this into the query builder?  I paste your expression into the query builder and it works fine.  Or are you building this query in VBA code?  How *exactly* are you using it?

Comment: Yeah I was using the query builder.  How should I use it. I select the field and column in the first column. In the second column do I just copy and paste that in across from the 'field' row?

Comment: This query should work all by itself in the query builder.  In other words, as long as you have the table *showing* (the table that contains [PlayerName]), paste your expression into `Field:` in the first column.  That should be all you need.  See if it runs with *just that*.  To verify in SQL view, it should look like this: `SELECT Left([FullName],InStr([FullName]," ")-1) AS FirstName FROM T_Crewmembers;`

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking there is a problem with the data in your original table, for example: there could be a space before "John" in "John Smith" (" John Smith").

Good way to check is using the replace function.

```
SELECT Replace([PlayerName]," ","-") as [TestName]
FROM YourTableName;
```

If there is a dash in front of your first name. That is the problem.

You can also try checking the function you are trying to use. instr([Start],[String1],[String2]) might require to have a 1 placed in the "[Start]" portion of the function.

Basically your new function would look as follows:

```
FirstName: Left([PlayerName],instr(1,[PlayerName]," ")-1)
```

Let me know if either of these solutions do not work and ill do more digging.